# fedora installation - failed to write boot loader configuration

Tags: fedora, grub2

I'm trying to install the latest version of Fedora Kinoite (KDE version of Fedora Silverblue) and I'm stuck with a "failed to write boot loader configuration" error.

I checked /tmp/storage.log and it seems that the source error is "failed to get canonical path of /boot/grub2". This error happens when Anaconda try to execute grub2-mkrelpath.

Here is the part of /tmp/storage.log where canonical path error appears:
[image: /tmp/storage.log]

I tried to create /boot/grub2 directory before starting installation, but it didn't help. I also tried some other potential solutions found on the net, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a dedicated /boot partition before starting installation resolved the problem.

Thanks to [MarcusMüller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/106650/marcus-m%c3%bcller) for the hint.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?